# Sharepoint Blog: enable/disable comments regarding field value of Posts

Tags: sharepoint, comments, blogs

I need to enable/disable post comments regarding the value of a new field in Post list. I don't see how to do this... Any ideas?

Why is there an error when converts to XSLT? Is possible to get the querystring to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to get that level of control with the standard blog component. Should be reasonably easy to implement using CKSEBE though.

Easiest method I can think of within the standard blog is to use jQuery to hide the comment form - that way you only need to get the value of the field appearing somewhere on the page.

Comment: Thanks Tom, Great Idea! I haven't think in Javascript to solve this problem. I will post my result.

Comment: it Works! I add a new field in Posts, and I show in Post.aspx modifying CAML. Then, I capture the value and use it for show/hide the 2 WebParts of comments with JQuery. Thanks Tom!